# Can't access properties of object returned from a collection?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code as follows:

```
[SandwichObject in ClassModule]

Option Explicit

Public bread As String
Public filling As String
Public calories As String

Function printDesc()
  Debug.Print ("bread: " & bread)
  Debug.Print ("filling: " & filling)
  Debug.Print ("calories: " & calories)
End Function

[macro]

Option Explicit

Sub collTest()

Dim coll As Collection
Set coll = New Collection

Dim s As SandwichObject
Set s = New SandwichObject
s.bread = "white"

Call coll.Add(s)
Call coll(1).printDesc

' Neither of the below lines work

' Gives "Variable uses an automation type not supported in visual basic"
'coll(1).bread = "brown"

' Runs, but doesn't print out a value. Debugging ?coll(1).bread in the immediate window gives Null
' Debug.Print ("Bread is " & coll(1).bread)

End Sub
```

As noted in the code comments, trying to access properties of the object returned from the collection gives errors. But I can call a method on the object fine without getting any errors. I'm not sure what I'm missing?

If it's relevant, this is running vba on mac excel.

Many thanks!

Comment: The code runs on my Windows PC and as the data type `collection` is native to VBA it should work on a MAC as well.  I am afraid I do not have any idea what the problem might be in your case.

Comment: Ah thanks for checking! (I don't have access to a windows machine at the moment). OK I'll chalk it up to mac excel..

Comment: You are welcome. As said code should work on a Mac as well. But maybe someone with   a Mac background is able to shed more light on this.